# Como faço para pegar url atual em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, path

Eu estou usando jQuery. Como faço para obter o caminho da URL atual e completa, quero atribuí-la a variável `url_atual`.

```
$("#id_ativo").change(function(){

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url_atual,
      ...
```

Comment: Para pegar em javascript faça isso, o restante não sei lhe ajudar: `function sayHello()
{
    var url = window.location.href.toString();
   alert(url);
}

sayHello();`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tente utilizar o código abaixo

```
var url_atual = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Como você fez para sua foto dar um zoom quando passa o mouse em cima dela? Procurei outros usuários e só encontrei você que acontece isso kkk.

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro isso acontece quando o usuário tem um nome de exibição "meio grande". Pode ver que o mesmo acontece nas perguntas/respostas [desse usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar:

```
window.location.protocol + "//" +
window.location.host +
window.location.pathname;
```

Se quiser mais opções, abra as **Ferramentas do desenvolvedor** e digite **window.location** no console e pressione enter. Você verá todas as opções que poderá utilizar!